# Show current price and price history of an asset on Stellar Testnet/Pubnet?

Tags: assets, testnet, history, trade, stellar-website

I learned that we need to stimulate the buy and sell transactions of a new asset to create a certain volume of trading records to make the current price and price history of that new asset appear on Stellar expert (please correct me if I am wrong). I tried it on Stellar Testnet, but nothing showed up. I noticed that other assets have no current prices or history too. Does it mean Testnet won't index the prices/history? I haven't tried on Stellar Pubnet yet. If trading stimulation would enable it on Stellar Pubnet, how much volume does it need? anything else needed to make it appear? Your detail instructions would be very appreciated!